# PyArg_ParseTuple default argument

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension

If I have the following function and the optional argument `myobj` is not passed, does `myobj` remain `NULL` or is it set to `Py_None`?

```
static PyObject * myfunc(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    PyObject * myobj = NULL;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|O", &myobj)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // ...
}
```

According [Parsing arguments and building values](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#parsing-arguments-and-building-values),

> `|` Indicates that the remaining arguments in the Python argument list are optional. The C variables corresponding to optional arguments should be initialized to their default value — when an optional argument is not specified, PyArg_ParseTuple() does not touch the contents of the corresponding C variable(s).

Does this apply to `PyObject *`s? It's obviously a pointer that exists in C so one could say it's a C variable, but it's a pointer to a python object so one could also say it does not count as a C variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will remain NULL. And of course a pointer to a struct is a C object.